# Django form - key error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form implemented in a ListView. The form is used for editing existing items. However I get a key error when i try to submit the form:
`File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\website\app\views.py", line 124, in form_valid
    id = self.kwargs['id']
KeyError: 'id'
[14/Dec/2016 21:42:09] "POST /car/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99346`

This is the main code:

```
class CarListFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CarListForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        obj = Car.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = CarListForm(instance=obj)
        car = form.save(commit=False)

        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            car.agency = Agency.objects.get(agency_id=9000)
        else:
            car.agency = self.request.user.agency
        car.save()
        return redirect('car_list')
```

What causes this key error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`id` is not in your `kwargs`, that is causing the KeyError. In fact, you don't need to load the car like that. Your method can be simplified to this:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class CarListFormView(UpdateView):
    model = Car
    form_class = CarListForm
    template_name = 'something/car_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        car = form.save(commit=False)

        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            car.agency = Agency.objects.get(agency_id=9000)
        else:
            car.agency = self.request.user.agency
        car.save()
        return redirect('car_list')
```

Comment: How do I add `id` to my `kwargs`? I don't think I can simplify like you proposed as I'm using the form to edit existing objects and not to add new objects. I apologize for not specifying that in my question.

Comment: You can simplify as I suggested if you use the `UpdateView`: `from django.views.generic import UpdateView`. This view knows that you are editing a  model and will not create a new one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Are you sure it is possible to mix a ListView and an UpdateView? `AttributeError at /car/
Generic detail view CarListFormView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this was a list view

Comment: OK, no problem. Thanks for trying. Do you know if it possible to add `id` to `kwargs`?

Comment: You could add it in the `post` method.